# Getting values in SQL from foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm currently strungling with SQL. I have two tables with the following columns:

```
table "A": columns "_id", "B_id" and "type"
table "B": columns "_id", "x", "y", "z"
```

"_id" is the row ID. "B_id" is a foreign key to a row ("_id") in table B.

Now I would like to get all "type" values of each row in table A together with the associated x, y and z value in table B.

I can get all rows in table A by:

```
SELECT type FROM A
```

Currently I have problems also retrieving the according x, y and z from B. How can this be done?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, but the answer to your question is to use `JOIN`.

Comment: I'd recommend a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT A.type, B.x, B.y, B.z FROM A, B where A.B_id=B._id`

or with more modern JOIN-Syntax:

`SELECT A.type, B.x, B.y, B.z FROM A JOIN B ON A.B_id=B._id`

This is for MySQL, but should work in other RDBMs.

Comment: Don't teach that ancient implicit join... Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax instead. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Thx, jarlh. I added JOIN to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the join as needed. Then just add the rows you need

```
 SELECT *

 FROM A
 JOIN b
 on A.B_ID = B._id
```